# Excel Indirect command returns #value

Tags: excel-indirect

Using COUNTIF to count the number of times the value "HW or SW" shows up in a column.  I am not sure how many rows of data I will end up with so I want to make that a variable, using INDIRECT.  This formula returns a #VALUE error and I cannot figure out why:  =COUNTIF('Daily_Data_Dump'!$G$2:INDIRECT("$G"&AB3),"HW_or_SW")  Where the value in cell "AB3" is 5000.  In my mind is should be the equivalent of =COUNTIF('Daily_Data_Dump'!$G$2:$G5000,"HW_or_SW"). Thanks for any help.

Comment: You dont need indirect if you use data-tabels for the data. Select data -> inser -> table -> write formula and select  area in data-table.

Comment: Yep .. but not using table in this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"In my mind is should be the equivalent of `=COUNTIF('Daily_Data_Dump'!$G$2:$G5000,"HW_or_SW")`."*

That is correct, the problem is something else. The adress is wrong, try:

`=COUNTIF('Daily_Data_Dump'!$G$2:INDIRECT("Daily_Data_Dump!$G"&AB3),"HW_or_SW")`

Comment: I think you are on the right path ... but getting #ref and formula errors now ....

Comment: Winner Winner !!! (typo on my end).. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome, glad i could help. If you would be so kind, could you accept my answer and upvote? This helps future readers to find the answer more quickly and rewards me with a few points as well. Happy coding!